# How to redirect "https://www.host.com" > "https://host.com" > "https://host..net" (only cert for host.com and host.net)

Tags: apache, redirect, https, http-redirect

I've been struggleing to get this redirect to work.

The main website is `host.net`

And I want `www.host.com` and `host.com` to redirect to `host.net` (site located external on antother server)

I have valid certificates for `host.com` and `host.net` but not for `www.host.com`

I've tried with this setup but the client gives a cert. error.
I've tried many combinations and sometimes I get one or the other to work, but not both redirects.

FROM .conf file example:

```
<VirtualHost *:443> 
   ..
   LogLevel alert rewrite:trace8
   RewriteEngine On
    
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} www.host.com [NC]
   RewriteRule ^/$ https://host.com [R=301] 
    
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} host.com [NC]
   RewriteRule ^/$ https://host.net [R=301,L]
```

LOG:

```
  init rewrite engine with requested uri /
  applying pattern '^/$' to uri '/'
  RewriteCond: input='host.com' pattern='www.host.com' [NC] => not-matched
  applying pattern '^/$' to uri '/'
  RewriteCond: input='host.com' pattern='host.com' [NC] => matched
  rewrite '/' -> 'https://host.net'
  explicitly forcing redirect with https://host.net
  escaping https://host.net for redirect
  redirect to https://host.net [REDIRECT/302]
```

Answer (score 1):

**Assumptions**

- you have a valid certificate for host.com and host.net
- not for [www.host.com](http://www.host.com) (like you said)

**Scenarios**

- you ask for `https://host.com`: you have a valid certificate, so it negotiates ok, and enters your VH.  This answers with a redirect to `https://host.net`.  This has a valid certificate, so you are ok.
- you ask for `https://www.host.com`: you do not have a valid certificate, so it complains on negotiation.  The negotiation happens *before* apache considers VH.  Once you accept the warning, it enters your VH, which sends you to `https://host.net`, which is again ok.

**Solutions**

- add a certificate for `https://www.host.com`
- get a certificate to cover both `https://host.com` and `httpd://www.host.com`.
- only accept connections for `www.host.com` on port 80, which redirects to `https://www.host.net`.

**Notes**

- your logs show that your configuration is good, it does what you expect.

Comment: I was heading in that direction, it's just a lot of extra "useless" www certs I have to make (or use wildcard certs). Are your sure it's not possble to make a redirect from `https://www.host.com` to `https//host.com` before SSL nogotiation?  I made it work several times, but I might have been the browser-chache playing me (even though doing cache-delete).

Comment: Not that I know, the request is not decrypted until the SSL negotiation is finished.

Comment: Damn, Let's encrypt doesn't support creation of wildcard certs using the HTTP-method only DNS-method, which required manual modification of TXT record :-( 
To create a cert for `www.host.com` I need to create a specific VH for that......it that really what other people do in regards to `https://www.host.com` <> `https://host.com` ? Your site should support both, we're not quite there yet where we can dump www.

Comment: At work we use wildcard certificates for that exact reason...  Or you can setup aliases in your CSR, but Let's Encrypt might not support that either...